# Resize background-image by html5 and css3

Tags: html, css

In this forum i read that i need to use JQ to resize background-image. but i don't know JQ and  want to resize background-image by css3. Can i do it? If possible show me the right direction, please.

I have two background images. One - texture with repeat (i don't want to scale it), And another one - below - whole picture (this one i don't want to repeat and want to resize when site change resolution (for ex on small screens).

```
    body { 
     padding-top: 60px; 
     padding-bottom: 40px;
     background-color:#ededed;
     background-image:url('http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/textura5.png'), url('http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/fone1.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991216/css3-resizing-a-background-image?rq=1

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867908/is-it-possible-in-css3-to-have-multiple-background-images-with-specific-size-for?rq=1

Comment: thank you! but i cant understand how i can select only one image in code. these examples have only one image

Comment: give the image a class and style it that way. `<img class="classname" >` and in your css, put `.classname { /* styles for the image here */ }`

Comment: The second link is for two background images, ie something like background-size: 2em 2em, 100% 100%;

Comment: i use WP and need to resize the image for whole body. And my body has two images. How i should act in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. The **40% 20%** section is the size for the first image, the **20% 15%** is for the second image. The repeat rules then specify that the first image doesn't repeat and the second does.

```
 body { 
     padding-top: 60px; 
     padding-bottom: 40px;
     background-color:#ededed;
     background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Fighting_kittens-1340.jpg'), url('http://thepersiankittens.com/Persian_Kittens.jpg'); 
     height: 1000px;
     width: 400px;
     background-size: 40% 20%, 20% 15%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    }
```

Here is an example that you can play around with http://jsbin.com/ojudel/1/edit

Change the percentages and you will see how it works. More information can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).

Comment: Thank you very for all answers! I tried all examples and in my case this - 2em 2em, 100% 100% - working good! I see that i need to learn more about this css3 rules and i will play with jsbin more. Only one things i couldnt do - save proportions for background pic in my fluid layout.

Comment: @Lucky You should be able to get it to work one way or another, using **auto** as a size, but then responsive bit is another thing entirely :)

Comment: Mookamafoob, thank you very much for answers!  I will play with auto in my fluid layout:)